# Multiple Strings in a Single TextView

Tags: android, string, textview

I have two `List<String>` **LIST A** and **LIST B**.Each `List<String>` have 10 lines. I need to display these Strings in TextView. But it should be like line by line.

Example:

```
LIST A - line 1 ( display first line of LIST A)

LIST B - line 1 ( display first line of LIST B)

LIST A - line 2 ( display 2nd line of LIST A)

LIST B - line 2 ( display 2nd line of LIST B)

LIST A - line 3 ( display 3rd line of LIST A)

LIST B - line 3 ( display 3rd line of LIST B)
```

etc....etc....

Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: @Shaishav  I hope it is possible by HTML.Have you got any idea ?

Comment: If you are more comfortable with HTML you could always build this in HTML and display it in a WebView :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I merged the both list and displayed the items in textview by using HTML and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate your `lists` and use `textview.append("yourline");` as per your convenient.

```
int listSize=10;
List<String> A = new ArrayList<String>(listSize),B = new ArrayList<String>(listSize);

for(int i=0;i<listSize;i++){
    textview.append(A.get(i)+"\n"+B.get(i)+"\n");
}
```

Comment: I know its sill question :)
But i mentioned above i need to display it by line by line.

Comment: But is it possible to copy the text ?

Comment: @Debugger copying the text is another problem. Android doesn't do text selection on TextViews by default.

Comment: @Debugger To do that you have to enable 'textIsSelectable' in xml.

Comment: @KirankumarZinzuvadia : i got the solution

Answer (score -1):

Just try with this example below. This is the answer with the output you want.

```
public class test extends AppCompatActivity {
        public ArrayList<String> alldata;
        TextView test;
        String str;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
            List<String> stockList = new ArrayList<String>();
            stockList.add("stock1");
            stockList.add("stock2");

            List<String> stockList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            stockList.add("stock3");
            stockList.add("stock4");

            stockList.addAll(stockList2);

            String[] stockArr = new String[stockList.size()];
            stockArr = stockList.toArray(stockArr);
            alldata = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < stockArr.length; i++) {

                str = stockArr[i].substring(0, stockArr[i].length()) + "<br>";

                alldata.add(str);
                str = "";
            }

            StringBuilder PostItems = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < alldata.size(); i++) {
                PostItems.append(alldata.get(i));

            }
            String StrigItem = String.valueOf(PostItems);

            test.setText(Html.fromHtml(StrigItem));
        }

    }
```